# If pointers are all the same size, how come we have to declare the type of object they point to?

Tags: c++, pointers

Does C++ enforce this only because it makes code more readable?

Comment: Why is this guy being down-voted so heavily? This is a genuine question...

Comment: Think about it.  If I do `somePtr -> someField`, how do I know what that means without knowing the pointer type?

Comment: _"because it makes code more readable?"_ No! we aren't duck-typing in c++. The compiler guarantees type consistency.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ -- The compiler doesn't "guarantee" type consistency -- there are many ways to get the wrong type of object address into a pointer.

Comment: Try using void * everywhere and see what behaviors you can implement (without casting).

Comment: I'm not saying it's not a *basic* question, but it doesn't make sense to down-vote someone just because they're a newbie to programming. If he's curious to learn why be so harsh on him?

Comment: @HotLicks Well, if you do the wrong things, like forced casting.

Comment: @Nate There's nothing about downvotes as _being harsh_ to anyone ad hominem. Honestly would you really judge this as a _'good question'_? Upvote, if you think so.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ - If you can get the wrong type by doing "the wrong things", the compiler is not "guaranteeing" anything.  In Java, eg, there's no way you get the wrong type into a reference (without escaping to C, that is).

Comment: @HotLicks I think what he means is that the compiler guarantees type consistency if you don't invoke UB, so it's a guarantee with a contingency clause.

Comment: @cdhowie - Of course you can argue that's true of assembler language (only assembler has *fewer* UB situations).

Answer (score 8):

If you want statements like `ptr->field` to make any sense to the compiler, it needs to know what pointers point to.

Answer (score 7):

You *don't* have to declare the type of object a pointer points to.  This is what the pointer-to-void (`void *`) type is -- a pointer to an object of an unknown type.

Of course, if you don't know the type of object then you cannot do anything useful with it, which is why C++ doesn't let you do much with a pointer-to-void except use it where a pointer-to-void is expected, or cast it to another pointer type.

You can also point to an *incomplete type*:

```
class Something;

Something * somethingPtr = nullptr;
```

Now we have a pointer to an object of type `Something`, but we don't know anything about that type and so we can't perform any operations on the target object:

```
// error: invalid use of incomplete type ‘class Something’
somethingPtr->foo();
```

Answer (score 1):

If you had:

```
struct foo
{
    int bar;
    int baz;
};

foo* myFoo = new foo;
```

How would you do `myFoo->bar` if you couldn't even tell that `myFoo` has a `bar` field?

Answer (score 1):

Or take the case of somePtr[i] or *(somePtr[i]), where i is multiplied by the object size in bytes, or somePtr++, where somePtr is effectively incremented by the object size.

Answer (score 0):

It makes code more readable but more importantly it makes code much safer.

You could imagine some syntax (like void*) where you have to tell it the type whenever you want to dereference or delete a pointer but that would make for unsafe,  unreadable code.